# How to handle Process com.example.xxx (pid xxxx ) has died ? Android 4.4

Tags: android, service, process, android-4.4-kitkat

How to handle Process com.example.xxx (pid xxxx ) has died ? I Use START_STICKY in my service not working in android KITKAT or higher. I think, i use Broadcast receiver to handle if my proces has died and my service restart automaticaly. Can you help me?